# Drush API for downloading module from a script

Tags: drush

I am trying to download module using Drush API via drush script as following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env drush
<?php

// check if we can bootstrap
$self = drush_sitealias_get_record('@self');
if (empty($self)) {
    drush_die("I can't bootstrap from the current location.", 0);
}

// goes to site directory
drush_op('chdir', $self['root']);


drush_include_engine('drupal', 'environment', drush_drupal_major_version());

//****how to download module

drush_module_enable(array('uuid'));

drush_print("Done.");
```

While i see an [Drush API](http://api.drush.org/api/drush/commands!core!drupal!environment_7.inc/master) for enabling, i don't see for downloading a module
How to download a module via Drush API from the script? Is there Drush API for automatically detect dependencies, download them and enable? Thank You

Drupal 7, Drush 5.8, Mac

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there's an API for this, I think it would be [drush_invoke_process](http://api.drush.org/api/drush/includes!command.inc/function/drush_invoke_process/6.x). I believe Drush uses that function internally when one command wants to execute another.

The primary function that executes the download work is [drush_pm_download()](http://api.drush.org/api/drush/commands!pm!download.pm.inc/function/drush_pm_download/6.x), so you could probably just call it directly as well.

And of course, as a last resort, you could use [`exec`](http://php.net/function.exec)`(drush @alias dl $module)`.

Comment: Yes, `drush_invoke_process("@self", "pm-download", array("uuid"));` is definitely the way to go here.  As for Drupal functions such as module_enable, you don't need to call the Drush function -- you may call the Drupal function directly.  That is much better than using drush_include_engine, which I would encourage you to stay away from.  Use `drush_invoke_process("@self", "pm-enable", array("uuid"))` if you must use Drush to enable the module.

Comment: Thank you that worked. Greg, thanks for the tip on running Drupal functions directly...i wasn't aware those are available when run as drush script